# firefox blocking TLS over multiple ports from same page

Tags: firefox, web, https, websocket, port

I am working on a web application that has an IIS webpage and a websocket server running. I am using the channel API for implementing TLS on the websocket server. On Chrome and IE 11/10 this works wonderfully. I have the websocket server running over port 8080 and the IIS webpage running over port 443.

With Firefox if I try to run that setup, the page will load the elements from IIS. It then will make a connection with the websocket server. Once the handshake is complete, Firefox kills the TLS connection.

Now if I run the IIS webpage unencrypted and connect to the encrypted websocket server over port 443 it will work.

I am trying to figure out a way to either enable this non standard configuration client side or a workaround on the server.

Comment: For further clarification: I have also tried running IIS on a non standard port over https with the websocket server running over 443. Firefox refuses the second connection in both cases. I think it may be that firefox is attempting to prevent multiple secure connections from one page but I am not sure why Firefox would be doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to this issue. When Firefox installs a certificate, it is bound to a specific port number. The client must connect to the server on that port to correct the issue. This is not present in either Chrome or IE. I am not sure if safari handles certificates in the same way.